# Wordpress Nivoslider Confilict

Tags: wordpress, nivo-slider

I was having a trouble with nivosilder plugin installed in wordpress as it uses the jquery 1.5.1 version and woocommerce plugin is using the 1.8.1 version.. The problem comes with on click event

Comment: have you tried using jquery migrate (on the official jquery downloads page) which is a plugin that implements backwards compatibility for older jquery versions or scripts that depend on them?  if not, add that and remove jquery 1.5.1 and see if that fixes it

Comment: I solved this problem by editing the nivoslider.php file, I changed the code where is calls the jquery.conflict() function to jquery.conflict(true)